# BitbucketからのClone速度について

Tags: bitbucket

bitbucketからcloneする際、httpsでもsshどちらも
自宅のフレッツ光では30KB～速くても150KB/sec程度しか速度が出ません。

Wimax2のモバイルルータや、自宅外のフリーWifi等を使用すると
数MB/secの速度が出ます。

ルーターの設定やネットワークの設定で見直すことで
改良するようなことはありますでしょうか。

Comment: 多分、求めている回答でないと思うのでコメントにしますが、このCloneの速度に関係なく、通信速度の計測を行ってどれくらい速度出るんでしょうか？、そもそもの話としてフレッツ光自体が速度の出るものじゃない気が…夜間帯の使用や、集合住宅などで回線の使用が集中すると速度は出ませんし…また、プロバイダでも変わりますよね…

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘の通りなのですが、bitbucket以外ではこんなに通信速度が遅くならないので、もしかしたら何か設定等有るのかと思って質問させてもらいました。

Comment: cloneするPCやclone先のディレクトリは自宅で試したときとそれ以外で同じなんですよね？時間や日を改めて試しても同程度の速度しか出ないのでしょうか。

Comment: 同じディレクトリをcloneしています。
何種類かのレポジトリで試しましたが同じでした。
自宅でcloneして速度がでない→すぐにWimax２回線につなぐと速度が出るといった状態です。